# How to reprocess raw logs in Sumologic

Tags: amazon-s3, sumologic

I added a AWS S3 collector to my sumologic account, then logs started be gathered.
In my case those are Application Load Balancer access logs.
I also let collector default boundaries detection to "Infer boundaries".

I noticed that some incoming request log entries of **https** type where merged with those of **h2** type.

I then decided to change boundaries detection by a regular expression.

My old log entries gathered by sumologic do not seem to be automatically reprocessed by this new configuration.

How to perform a global reprocessing of logs gathered by my collector so they can be properly parsed?

Answer (score 1):

I always *thought* you could update the "Collection should begin" property on the source configuration to a different / previous time from the original value and it would re-ingest from there. If not, however, you might want to consider just creating a new source and backdating that property. https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/02Sources-for-Hosted-Collectors/Amazon-Web-Services/AWS-S3-Source

Comment: It seems à good idea. I'll try it and mark as answered if succeed. Thank you for the path